# Get list of documents with CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, caml-query

I am trying to retrieve only documents from a library. When I use this CAML:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Lookup'>0</Value></Eq></Where>
```

I get only the documents in the root. No items form the sub folders.

when I use this:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value></Eq></Where>
```

I get only folders coming in the results.

The reason I need this is to delete all files under the document library and keep the folder structure.

any help would be much appreciated.

My folder structure for test purposes:

```
My Document Library
   -Folder1
      -Document1
      -Document2
   -Document3
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to retrieve it using Recursive All. for ex. in CSOM,

```
var caml = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
caml.set_viewXml("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Neq></Where></Query></View>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two code blocks are identical.  I think you might have a copy/paste error.

The usual way to get all nested documents from a CAML query is to use 
`<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>`

around the outside of the where clause.

Comment: `FSObjType` is 0 in the first block and 1 in the second.

Comment: I tried to add View, it did not change anything and I added 
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=`"RecursiveAll`"" in my code and started to do something but still not quiet right. it should bring me only 3 results(please check my folder structure above) It also brings Folder1 in the results.

Comment: FSObjType of 0 and RecursiveAll for ViewScope combined has always worked for me.  Post your updated code, there may be a typo somewhere.

Comment: I was looking to retrieve only documents not folders. So this answer is still not complete...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally did to solve the problem:

I added

```
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=`"RecursiveAll`""
```

to my code and used this CAML Query:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Lookup'>0</Value></Eq></Where>
```

Thanks for the support!